# DeMorgans Law unable to simplify a boolean expression

Tags: demorgans-law

There is a boolean expression `(A+B)(AB)'`. 
The answer's truth table compared to this initial have the matching combinations that are resembling one of a XOR gate. I'm wondering if there is an identity or it is possible to further simplify the finished answer into something that resembles a XOR gate. My working out is as follows

```
(A+B)(AB)'
= (A+B)(A'+B')
= AA' + AB' + BA' + BB'
= 0 + AB' + BA' + 0
= AB' + BA'
```

Im not sure if this is fully simplified or if there was another path to follow that would give the correct answer. 
(The initial converted to a circuit will have 4 gates while the "simplified" version will have 5 unless I miscounted)

Thank you in advance

Comment: There’s not much to do here. These are the formulas you have for xor and as for building on and/or/not gates the original one is the “simpler” one.

Comment: But to simplify corresponds with the gates in a circuit. When the initial expression has 4 gates and the simplified version has 5, thats the opposite of what should happen isn't it? There should, theoretically, be 1 since the answer is A xor B, was just wondering if there was an identity to change say AB' to A xor B or if there was something I missed on another line

Comment: The original is the simplified version, it can’t go any further. Both can be converted into “A xor B” as a whole since they do define the exclusive or function. So whenever there is AB’ + BA’ it is a xor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Identity for the XOR gate is `(A+B)(AB)'`. Although it is not displayed in most sites that iterate DeMorgans laws, their truth tables have common outputs and when XOR is googled, the formula `(A+B)(AB)'` is shown. Therefore, `(A+B)(AB)' = A xor B` or the simplified version `AB' + BA' = A xor B`.